# JHAML and play framework?

Tags: playframework, haml

Does anyone have any experience combining these two together? [JHAML is a Java implementation of HAML.](https://github.com/raymyers/JHaml) I'm starting to like HAML a lot and it would be great if it could be used with Play.

Any experience anyone?

Answer (score 0):

See http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/4898f67bb1a606c1 . Also, [Scaml](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/scaml-reference.html) might be of interest.

Better yet, can you use Rails instead? :) [Yeah, I know, but I had to ask.]